# In Contentful - MultipleEntryReferenceEditor how can we add more Action?..I need a "Duplicate" field button

Tags: contentful, contentful-api, contentful-management

In Contentful - MultipleEntryReferenceEditor how can we add more Action?..

I want duplicate action that will add a copy of the items.

I need a "Duplicate"  that will duplicate the Entry.

This will come just under Edit, Remove, Move to top and Move to bottom.

I am trying to make it easier to add content to contentful faster